# How to mock PrivateObject in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, privateobject.invoke

I have this code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        TextBox txtBox= new TextBox() { Text = "Test" };

        PrivateObject privateObj= new PrivateObject(someObject);
        var mockObj = new Mock<PrivateObject>();
        mockObj.Setup(x => x.Invoke("SomeMethod", It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

        object result = privateObj.Invoke("DoSomething", txtBox, EventArgs.Empty);

        Assert.AreEqual(txtBox.Text, string.Empty);
    }
```

The method "DoSomething" calls "SomeMethod" method, which returns a boolean type. How can I Mock SometMetod, so that when I call it, he returns what I need?

Comment: What's `someObject` in `new PrivateObject(someObject)`?

Comment: Take a look at this article and see if it can fit your scenario. https://adamprescott.net/2012/08/28/unit-testing-and-private-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I should have investigated you problem more thoroughly. I didn't realize that `PrivateObject` was an already existing class of the .NET framework.

My answer is not going to answer your problem directly but I'm leaving it here regardless. I assume you use Moq and therefore the following parts of classes are not available for mocking:

- non-virtual members
- static members
- extension methods
- any member of sealed classes
- fields

Private members can be tested, I'm not saying it's generally wrong. Usually the need to test private members is a sign of bad code design, though.

Private methods and fields are implementation details and should not affect your class' functionality. Don't treat each method as a unit, rather do treat the class as a unit. Test your class' *behavior* and that it does what it should do and don't test *how* it does it.

<s>object result = privateObj.Invoke("DoSomething", txtBox, EventArgs.Empty);
You are calling the `DoSomething` method on `privateObj` and not on `mockObj` which is *not setup* to return what you "need".</s>

What should your unit test achieve? Mocking behavior of *your system under test* is kind of contradictory because test results will not be representative for the system's actual behavior.

I guess what you could do is to extract the functionality of `SomeMethod`  from `PrivateObject` into a dependecy of it, let's say `IHaveSomeMethod`.

```
public interface IHaveSomeMethod {
    bool SomeMethod();
}

public class PrivateObject {
    private IHaveSomeMethod dependency;

    public PrivateObject(???SomeObject someObject???, IHaveSomeMethod ihsm) {
        // ...
        this.iHaveSomeMethod = ihsm;
        // ...
    }

    public void DoSometing() {
        // ...
        iHaveSomeMethod.SomeMethod();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you could test like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    TextBox txtBox= new TextBox() { Text = "Test" };

    var mockObj = new Mock<IHaveSomeMethod>();
    mockObj.Setup(x => x.Invoke("SomeMethod", It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

    var sut = new PrivateObject(???someObject???, mockObj.Object); // system under test
    object result = sut.Invoke("DoSomething", txtBox, EventArgs.Empty);

    Assert.AreEqual(txtBox.Text, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: That is not how [PrivateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) works.

Comment: @Nkosi oh wow, that's my bad. I updated my answer, even though it doesn't directly answer OPs problem